# Windows Phone 8.1 CookieContainer and XMLConnect cookie issue

Tags: c#, magento, cookies, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 shopping application that communicates with a Magento XMLConnect API. My problem is that the cookies sent by the server are stored in my CookieContainer, but when I send a request to the server the cookies aren't sent. If I manually re-add the cookies to the CookieContainer with explicitly setting the domain and the key-value pair, the cookies are sent and everything works fine. This solution is OK for adding the appcode cookie and the screensize cookie manually needed for app init, but of course I can't do that with the frontend cookie (which identifies the user), because that's not constant. So the result is that the frontend cookie is always missing from my request so the server can't identify the user i.e. user isn't logged in. 
Any idea for a solution? Is it a known behavior of the CookieContainer when working with XMLConnect?

```
 public static CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    public static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    private static System.Net.Http.HttpClient client;

 public static async Task<string> httpGET(string url)
    {

        string resp = "";
        byte[] response = new byte[] { };

        if (cookies.Count == 0)
        {
            cookies.Add(new Uri(url...), new Cookie("app_code", "defand1"));
            cookies.Add(new Uri(url...), new Cookie("screen_size", "2560x2560"));    
        }
        try
        {
            response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
            resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length);
            string httpResponse = resp;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return resp;
    }

     public static async Task<string> httpPOST(string url)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage repi = client.GetAsync(baseURL).Result;
        string resp = "";

        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Task<string> getStringAsync = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        resp = await getStringAsync;
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code! How can we help without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: You should edit your question and add your code.

Comment: At what point do you pass your cookie container to your HttpClient?